# Facebook PSID Migration from ASID

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Help... I'm new to developing trying to figure out what i need to do in order to migrate asid's to psid's in my application. I've used Postman to send a post request as described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/access-tokens/psid-api/. I'm using php project and need to figure out where i need to put this post request in my project. Do i need to do it for every user I have using my application or can i do one request that will apply to every user.

Comment: _“Do i need to do it for every user I have using my application or can i do one request that will apply to every user.”_ - the explanation of the `user_ids` parameter of that API call answers that question already, doesn’t it?

Answer (score 0):

> If you take no action, the switch to PSIDs will automatically occur at the end of the 180-day grace period.

It is actually just a switch in the settings.

Comment: Thankyou, I have the latest sdk so it should migrate without a problem